# Prestashop responsive theme not working in mobile

Tags: responsive-design, prestashop

I have developed responsive design for prestashop 1.5.2 . When I used some online simulators like quirktools.com to test the pages, it's working fine and all the pages are loading properly.  When I tested the same in mobile, the pages are calling properly like in the simulator, but the links are not working.

Comment: have you done any research on their community?

Comment: Yes i had done the research and observed no error also as i described above the pages are working properly in quirktools.com and other simulators.The only problem is links are not working in mobile browsers.